# Ruby on Rails Internationalization-How do I include line breaks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, line-breaks

I'm using ruby on rails and internationalization and I want to know how to insert a line break for a string.

For example:
en:
title1: "Same Products,Better Rates"

I want it to appear like this on my site:

Same Products,
Better Rate

I tried doing /n but that wasn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when your render the view you should use html_safe:

```
"Same Products, <br/> Better Rates".html_safe
```

Comment: this is render html with break it will work unless you try in console, does you try in console?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some thing like

```
title_1: |
 Same Products,
 Better rates.
```

```
I18n.t 'title_1'
```

> my console output

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)
 2.1.1 :001 > I18n.t 'title_1'
 => "Same Products,\nBetter rates.
```

> config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
 hello: "Hello world"
 title_1: |
  Same Products,
  Better rates.
```

Comment: hmm I tried that right now and that also doesn't work. Am I doing it right?
Rates:
  slogan: |
      Same Products, 
      Better Rates

And then in my code I put:
<%= t('rates.slogan') %>

Comment: just updated the answer , please let me know if it works as same

Comment: hmm just tried it again. did not work! Not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Am I just inserting that code in my en.yml file. I also tried adding the ":" to the code just now, doens't work :(